# Where did they get the transporter coordinates for the Defiant in "The Tholian Web"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

At the start of the *Star Trek* episode "The Tholian Web" the crew of the *Enterprise* can somehow "see" the wreck of the *Defiant* although it doesn't register on the ship's sensors. Then they beam over to check things out.

If it doesn't register on the sensors then where did they get the coordinates for the transporter?

Comment: In a deleted scene they are seen transporting redshirts at random locations until one of them returns without suffering from explosive decompression... Just kidding, of course XD.

Answer (score 6):

If they can see it visually, that's enough to know its distance and orientation.  With that, because it's a sister ship, they exactly know the size and interior layout, so that's enough to go on.  Of course they might not know the exact location of crew members, so might take a risk of beaming into one, but maybe the writers didn't think of that.

Comment: I guess - they need a pretty good estimate to avoid beaming into walls...